# fade a picture and bring up others in a presentation

Tags: graphics, presentations

Actually, I have seen some presentation that an image fade and other 3 images appeared there. or one image went smaller in top and two images appeared in down of a page 
Is there anyone know how to make such slides ? I really appreciate any comment .

Thanks

Comment: Like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65733/7883 ?

Comment: @Thérèse thanks for your message, Not really, imagine there is a page , first we show an image in full size then click , that image becomes smaller and goes on top of the presentation and two other images side by side come under it .

Comment: Seems to be an `\temporal<>{}{}{}` job.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may want to look into slide transitions, see `14.3 Slide Transitions` of the beamer user guide.

A short example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \transfade<1-2>
  \includegraphics<1>[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \includegraphics<2>[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \includegraphics<2>[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```